Uploading file from different source in Uppy to AWS S3
We are using Uppy to upload files to AWS S3, our current workflow only supports uploading file from device to S3 without Uppy Companion. However, we want to add more source like Google Drive, One Drive, Link or Box in upload process. Is there any way we can add these without using Companion and still files get uploaded to S3 as most of the source upload files to web-server only.
Reason for not using Companion: As companion is server-side plugin and consume server, and we want downloading from source and uploading them to S3 will be handled by frontend only.
